# Are the outcomes of the numpy.where method on a pandas dataframe calculated on the full array or the filtered array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I want to use a `numpyp.where` on a pandas dataframe to check for existence of a certain string in a column. If the string is present apply a split-function and take the second list element, if not just take the first character. However the following code doesn't work, it throws a `IndexError: list index out of range` because the first entry contains no underscore:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','a_1','b_','b_2_3']})
df["B"] = np.where(df.A.str.contains('_'),df.A.apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1]),df.A.str[0])
```

Only calling `np.where` returns an array of indices for which the condition holds true, so I was under the impression that the `split`-command would only be used on that subset of the data:

```
np.where(df.A.str.contains('_'))
Out[14]: (array([1, 2, 3], dtype=int64),)
```

But apparently the `split`-command is used on the entire unfiltered array which seems odd to me as that seems like a potentially big number of unnecessary operations that would slow down the calculation.

I'm not asking for an alternative solution, coming up with that isn't hard.

I'm merely wondering if this is an expected outcome or an issue with either pandas or numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python isn't a ["lazy" language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) so code is evaluated immediately.  generators/iterators do introduce some lazyness, but that doesn't apply here

if we split your line of code, we get the following statements:

1. `df.A.str.contains('_')`
2. `df.A.apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1])`
3. `df.A.str[0]`

Python has to evaluate these statements before it can pass them as arguments to `np.where`

to see all this happening, we can rewrite the above as little functions that displays some output:

```
def fn_contains(x):
    print('contains', x)
    return '_' in x

def fn_split(x):
    s = x.split('_')
    print('split', x, s)
    # check for errors here
    if len(s) > 1:
        return s[1]

def fn_first(x):
    print('first', x)
    return x[0]
```

and then you can run them on your data with:

```
s = pd.Series(['a','a_1','b_','b_2_3'])
np.where(
  s.apply(fn_contains),
  s.apply(fn_split),
  s.apply(fn_first)
)
```

and you'll see everything being executed in order.  this is basically what's happening "inside" numpy/pandas when you execute things

Comment: So it first evaluates all three of those inner statements before going into the enclosing `np.where`. And without the `np.where` there is no knowledge about using the first statement as a filter for the second and third statements. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: sounds about right, have updated with a demo so you can hopefully see what's happening

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion `numpy.where` only set values by condition, so second and third arrays are counted for all data - filtered and also non filtered.

If need apply some function only for filtered values:

```
mask = df.A.str.contains('_')
df.loc[mask, "B"] = df.loc[mask, "A"].str.split('_').str[1]
```

In your solution is error, but problem is not connected with `np.where`. After split by `_` if not exist value, get one eleemnt list, so selecting second value of list by `[1]` raise error:

```
print (df.A.apply(lambda x: x.split('_')))
0          [a]
1       [a, 1]
2        [b, ]
3    [b, 2, 3]
Name: A, dtype: object

print (df.A.apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So here is possible use pandas solution, if performance is not important, because strings functions are slow:

```
df["B"] = np.where(df.A.str.contains('_'), 
                   df.A.str.split('_').str[1],
                   df.A.str[0])
```

Comment: I'm surprised that `df.A.str.split('_').str[1]` works, wouldn't have thought of using the `.str`-accessor on a list. I did come up with this solution: `df.A.apply(lambda x: x.split('_')[1] if "_" in x else x[0])`.