# Concatenating two columns in pandas dataframe without adding extra spaces at the end when the second column contains NaN/empty strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas data frame:

```
> print(tpl_subset)
>
         Fullname                 Infrasp                   Authorship
Lilium abchasicum                     NaN                        Baker
    Lilium affine                     NaN          Schult. & Schult.f.
Lilium akkusianum                     NaN                     Gämperle
 Lilium albanicum                     NaN                      Griseb.
 Lilium albanicum           subsp. jankae              (A.Kern.) Nyman
Lilium albiflorum                     NaN                        Hook.
     Lilium album                     NaN                       Houtt.
   Lilium amabile             var. flavum                      Y.N.Lee
   Lilium amabile        var. immaculatum                      T.B.Lee
   Lilium amabile     var. kwangnungensis            Y.S.Kim & W.B.Lee
              ...                     ...                          ...
```

I am trying to concatenate the first two columns into a new one only if the value of the second column is not `NaN`.

What I have been doing so far is simply concatenating the two columns while replacing `NaN` by an empty string.

```py
tpl_subset['Tmp'] = tpl_subset['Fullname'] + ' ' + tpl_subset['Infrasp'].fillna('')
```

The problem is that I end up with unwanted whitespaces at the end of the string when the value of the second column is `NaN` (e.g. `'Lilium abchasicum'` becomes `'Lilium abchasicum  '`), which forces me to do extra steps to remove them.

These steps will be repeated hundreds of times on datasets containing hundred thousands rows each, so I'm looking for something efficient in term of performance. Using a `for` loop with an `if else` statement is not option.

**Q.:** is there an efficient and more direct way to do this?

The desired column output is:

```
                               Tmp
                 Lilium abchasicum
                     Lilium affine
                 Lilium akkusianum
                  Lilium albanicum
    Lilium albanicum subsp. jankae
                 Lilium albiflorum
                      Lilium album
        Lilium amabile var. flavum
   Lilium amabile var. immaculatum
Lilium amabile var. kwangnungensis
```

**Edit:**

A quick performance comparison between `numpy.where()` and `radd(' ').fillna('')` on the whole dataset (~1.2 millions rows):

```
In:
import timeit

s = '''
import pandas
import numpy as np
tpl_data = pandas.read_csv('~/phd/Data/TPL/tpl_all_species.csv', sep = '\t')
tpl_fn = tpl_data['Fullname']
tpl_inf = tpl_data['Infrasp']
tpl_concat = tpl_fn + ' ' + tpl_inf
'''

tmp1 = "tpl_data['tmp1'] = np.where(tpl_inf.isnull(), tpl_fn, tpl_concat)"
tmp2 = "tpl_data['tmp2'] = (tpl_fn + tpl_inf.radd(' ').fillna(''))"

print('np.where():', timeit.Timer(tmp1, setup = s).repeat(repeat = 3, number = 10))
print('radd():', timeit.Timer(tmp2, setup = s).repeat(repeat = 3, number = 10))

Out:
np.where(): [0.7466984760000002, 0.7332379689999993, 0.7483021389999998]
radd(): [2.2832963809999995, 2.320076223000001, 2.299452007000003]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use `np.where`:

```
df['Tmp'] = np.where(df['Infrasp'].isnull(), df['Fullname'], df['Fullname'] + ' ' + df['Infrasp'])
```

Comment: But that just ditches numpy/pandas and ends up as a `for` loop

Comment: @roganjosh If jezrael didn't post before me i would do his solution :P

Comment: I don't think their solution is the most efficient.

Comment: @roganjosh Haha like me you call that jezrael their

Comment: @roganjosh Better now?

Comment: @jezrael Better now?

Comment: sure, better one

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant by my comment on their answer. I think this will be more performant

Comment: @roganjosh Yeah, maybe an up-vote would help, nah don't bother

Answer (score 2):

First idea is add from right side space by [`Series.radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.radd.html), what is not added to values with missing values:

```
tpl_subset['Tmp'] = (tpl_subset['Fullname'] + tpl_subset['Infrasp'].radd(' ').fillna(''))
```

**Performance**:

```
print (tpl_subset)
        Fullname     Infrasp
0         Lilium  abchasicum
1  Lilium affine         NaN

#200k rows
tpl_subset = pd.concat([tpl_subset] * 100000, ignore_index=True)


In [235]: %timeit tpl_subset['Tmp1'] = np.where(tpl_subset['Infrasp'].isnull(), tpl_subset['Fullname'], tpl_subset['Fullname'] + ' ' + tpl_subset['Infrasp'])
74.8 ms ± 7.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [236]: %timeit tpl_subset['Tmp2'] = (tpl_subset['Fullname'] + tpl_subset['Infrasp'].radd(' ').fillna(''))
63.2 ms ± 625 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [237]: %timeit tpl_subset['Tmp3'] = [f'{a} {b}' if b == b else a for a, b in zip(tpl_subset['Fullname'], tpl_subset['Infrasp'])]
72.4 ms ± 1.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to use `np.where()` than string concatenation and then a `.str` method?

Comment: @roganjosh - just tested and seems not.

Comment: So I'm seeing, and I'm confused by that :)

Comment: @roganjosh - I think reason is np.where count each series separately, explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56749469/2901002)

Comment: I'm still not sure why it would work that way. This almost suggests that it's quicker to do string formatting on every row and then "roll back" on the issues, than do string formatting only when a condition is true. That seems wonky but I guess I have some research to do.

Comment: @roganjosh - yes, I only guess problem shouldbe porrly support in numpy for strings...

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for your input. Your method works. I also tried `np.where()` and it seems like it is slightly faster on my dataset though.

Comment: @jezrael I added a performance comparison of both method in the question.